# Setup VLAN on linux bridge for virtual machines with systemd

Tags: debian, kvm, bridge, vlan, systemd-networkd

I want to switch to *systemd* and with this I have to setup the linux bridge for my virtual machines in KVM to use VLAN.

Having Debian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch), using its *systemd-networkd* and *libvirt*. NOT using oldstyle networking with `ifupdown` (deinstalled it).

I'm sitting on harley, my all day workstation for testing and setup the bridge on the host.

```
harley$ cat /etc/systemd/network/08-br0.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
[Bridge]
VLANFiltering=true
STP=false  
harley$ cat /etc/systemd/network/12-br0_add-enp1s0.network
[Match]
Name=enp1s0
[Network]
Bridge=br0
[BridgeVLAN]
VLAN=10
[BridgeVLAN]
VLAN=20
[BridgeVLAN]
VLAN=30  
harley$ cat /etc/systemd/network/16-br0_up.network
[Match]
Name=br0
```

Cleanup an old bridge from testing and setup a new one from scratch:

```
harley$ sudo ip link set dev br0 down && sudo ip link del dev br0
harley$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
harley$
```

It's all in place now:

```
harley$ cat /sys/class/net/br0/bridge/vlan_filtering
1
harley$ cat /sys/class/net/br0/bridge/stp_state
0
harley$ sudo bridge vlan show
port    vlan ids
enp1s0   1 PVID Egress Untagged
         10
         20
         30  
br0      1 PVID Egress Untagged
harley$
```

Now I start the virtual machine, login and show its interface setting:

```
harley$ virsh start --console deb9-test
```

login

```
deb9-test$ cat /etc/systemd/network/08-vlan10.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=vlan10
Kind=vlan
[VLAN]
Id=10  
deb9-test$ cat /etc/systemd/network/12-vlan10_attach-to-if.network
[Match]
Name=ens2
[Network]
VLAN=vlan10  
deb9-test$ cat /etc/systemd/network/16-vlan10_up.network
[Match]
Name=vlan10
[Network]
Address=192.168.10.57/24
Gateway=192.168.10.1
DNS=192.168.10.8
```

But pinging the gateway gives no result at this stage:

```
deb9-test$ ping -c1 192.168.10.1
PING 192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.10.57 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable  
--- 192.168.10.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

The bridge shows now:

```
harley$ sudo bridge vlan show
port    vlan ids
enp1s0   1 PVID Egress Untagged
         10
         20
         30  
br0      1 PVID Egress Untagged  
vnet0    1 PVID Egress Untagged
```

I have to modify it:

```
harley$ sudo bridge vlan del dev enp1s0 vid 1
harley$ sudo bridge vlan del dev br0 vid 1 self
harley$ sudo bridge vlan del dev vnet0 vid 1
harley$ sudo bridge vlan add vid 10 dev vnet0
```

VM works now:

```
deb9-test$ ping -c1 192.168.10.1
PING 192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.843 ms  
--- 192.168.10.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.843/0.843/0.843/0.000 ms
```

After modification this is what I want, simple and clean:

```
harley$ sudo bridge vlan show
port    vlan ids
enp1s0   10
         20
         30  
br0     None
vnet0    10
```

**And finaly now my Question:**
how can I make Debian to do this for me right up before the VMs interface comes up, so it can get its ip-address with DHCP?

Comment: Add `[VLAN]
\ Id=10` to `08-br0.netdev`

Comment: @gdahlm Thanks, tried it, but with no result. _The "[VLAN]" section only applies for netdevs of kind "vlan"_. We have `Kind=bridge` [systemd.netdev](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.netdev.html)

Comment: For such applications I recommend using [Open vSwitch](http://openvswitch.org/) instead of plain Linux bridges and VLAN interfaces.

Comment: @Ferenc Wágner This is very basic usage of VLAN-switching. Do you mean, linux bridge isn't usable for this in general? Does `Open vSwitch` better scale together with `systemd-networkd` and `libvirt`?

Comment: @Ferenc Wágner btw. the Problem isn't linux bridge. It works like a charme.

Comment: I don't know the extent and the possible quirks of the Linux bridge VLAN implementation and iproute2. OvS has explicit support in libvirt, which works well for me. On the other hand, `systemd-networkd` gave me grief in much simpler settings, when early boot services (like rpcbind) required networking.

Comment: Yes, I read this [Setting VLAN tag (on supported network types only)][1] but I don't understand it without testing. What does it mean "VLAN tagging transparent to the guest"? Does the guests see the tagged packets? I want that. I found a quite simply solution. The only problem is to tell `libvirt` to give the right vlan-id to the right virtual interface on startup of a domain. The kernel Linux bridge and iproute2 is stable but I found `systemd-networkd` is buggy. I will post my solution next days. Can I answer my own question?


  [1]: https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementVlanTag

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of your comment because you didn't mention my name. Anyway, what you worked out for Linux bridges in your answer is supported out of the box for Open vSwitch bridges, as you found in the libvirt documentation. Nice work, btw!

Answer (score 3):

**PLEASE NOTE:**
This configuration is deprecated and no longer supported. I have decided to continue it on server**fault** at [VLAN support with libvirt for linux bridge to virtual machines](https://serverfault.com/q/1051294/458473), because I think it better fit to that site according to the policies. If you want improved scripts, then look there.

---

I've worked on it and found a solution. Here is it in short. Look there for a [more detailed description](http://wiki.hoeft-online.de/VLAN_for_virtual_machines#linux_bridge_with_libvirt_hook_scripts).

We have to tell `libvirt` to set the right VLAN-ID to the dynamic created virtual network interface (e.g. vnet0) added to the bridge on startup of a domain (guest). For this we can use [libvirt hook scripts](https://www.libvirt.org/hooks.html). I do this in three steps.

**Step 1: define VLAN-ID the virtual machine belongs to**

For this we have an extra [element <metadata> in Domain XML format](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsMetadata) for custom metadata. We can simply add the information to the static configuration with `harley$ virsh edit deb9-test` like this (look only at the <metadata> element):

```
harley$ virsh dumpxml deb9-test | head -n9
 <domain type='kvm' id='1'>
   <name>deb9-test</name>
  <uuid>70d56a28-795d-4010-9403-513a4bd6b66a</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <my:home xmlns:my="http://hoeft-online.de/my/">
      <my:vlan>10</my:vlan>
    </my:home>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
```

**Step 2: get information on startup from the runtime XML-config of the domain**

The [hook script](https://www.libvirt.org/hooks.html) gets information on its standard input. This is the XML-config of the running VM. We can also get it with `harley$ virsh dumpxml deb9-test` when the VM is running. I use XSLT with `xmlstarlet` to get needed information with a xsl-stylesheet. I can test with `harley$ virsh dumpxml deb9-test | xmlstarlet tr qemu.xsl`. Here is the stylesheet:

```
harley$ cat /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This stylesheet extracts the VLAN-ID and the target device of the
     bridge from the domain-xml given to the libvirt hook-script "qemu".
     Example output: <meta><vlan>10</vlan><dev>vnet0</dev></meta>
-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:my="http://hoeft-online.de/my/" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"
       encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/domain">
    <meta>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </meta>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="metadata/my:home/my:vlan">
    <vlan>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </vlan>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='interface[@type="bridge"]/target'>
    <dev>
      <xsl:value-of select="@dev"/>
    </dev>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
harley$
```

**Step 3: set VLAN-ID to the dynamic virtual network interface vnet***

With information from the stylesheet we can now setup the network interface with a [hook script](https://www.libvirt.org/hooks.html). Make it executable.

```
harley$ cat /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu
#!/bin/bash
#/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu
# Docs: https://www.libvirt.org/hooks.html
# If you make a new hook script then 'sudo systemctl restart libvirtd'.

# On startup of the domain (guest) This script does:
# Get Metadata VLAN-ID of the guest and target device of the bridge from
    # the domain-xml available on standard input. It is the runtime
    # version from 'virsh dumpxml domainname'. For extracting the
    # information we use a XSL-stylesheet. Example input into $META:
    # <meta><vlan>10</vlan><dev>vnet0</dev></meta>
# Select $DEV  from $META
# Select $VLAN from $META
# Set $VLAN to $DEV on the bridge

case "$2" in
  prepare)
    ;;
  start)
    META=$(/usr/bin/xmlstarlet tr /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu.xsl -)
    DEV=$(echo "$META" | /usr/bin/xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/meta/dev')
    VLAN=$(echo "$META" | /usr/bin/xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/meta/vlan')
    if [[ -n $DEV && -n $VLAN ]]; then
      /sbin/bridge vlan add vid "$VLAN" dev "$DEV"
    fi
    ;;
  started)
    ;;
  stopped)
    ;;
  release)
    ;;
  migrate)
    ;;
  restore)
    ;;
  reconnect)
    ;;
  attach)
    ;;
  *)
    echo "qemu hook called with unexpected options $*" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
harley$
```