# systemd-networkd bridge does not work with VLAN

Tags: networking, bridge, systemd-networkd, vlan

I am trying to configure one bridge per VLAN (without VLAN filtering) with `systemd-networkd` for easy configuration of libvirt VMs on Debian 12.

This does work as expected without VLAN and it does work with VLAN with some manual help (`ip link set master ...`). The problem symptom is that `systemd-networkd` does create the bridge and VLAN interfaces but does not connect them:

```
2: onbunten: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master brlan state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:92:26:b7:a9:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: brlan: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c6:50:f5:f2:22:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.222/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global brlan
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: brvlan2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 46:ba:f7:a8:3d:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: brvlan3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:96:9b:cc:69:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: onbunten.4@onbunten: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:92:26:b7:a9:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: onbunten.2@onbunten: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:92:26:b7:a9:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: onbunten3@onbunten: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:92:26:b7:a9:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The `onbunten.2` / `onbunten3` pattern difference is intentional; for testing whether that made any difference.

I have found descriptions on the Internet which seem to state that what I did is the solution. I also found the statement

> This configuration is deprecated and no longer supported

on this site ([the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394937/32191)); unfortunately without a clear explanation what exactly is supposed to be deprecated (I did not find any such hints in the Systemd man pages).

I have been running `systemd-networkd` in debug mode (`SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug`) but among the 500 lines of logging I do not notice any which are related to the VLAN and bridge interfaces simultaneously. No error messages.

## the config files

### this is what does work

```
==> 31-brlan.netdev <==
[NetDev]
Name=brlan
Kind=bridge
```

```
==> 32-brvlan2.netdev <==
[NetDev]
Name=brvlan2
Kind=bridge
```

```
==> 33-brvlan3.netdev <==
[NetDev]
Name=brvlan3
Kind=bridge
```

```
==> 41-onbunten-vlans.network <==
[Match]
Type=ether
Name=onbunten

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=no
VLAN=onbunten.2
VLAN=onbunten3
VLAN=onbunten.4
Bridge=brlan
```

```
==> 61-brlan-onbunten.network <==
[Match]
Name=onbunten

[Network]
Bridge=brlan
```

```
==> 71-brlan.network <==
[Match]
Name=brlan

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=no
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
IgnoreCarrierLoss=yes

[Address]
Address=192.168.2.222/24
```

### this is what does NOT work

```
==> 62-brvlan2-onbunten2.network <==
[Match]
Name=onbunten.2

[Network]
Bridge=brvlan2
```

```
==> 63-brvlan3-onbunten3.network <==
[Match]
Name=onbunten3

[Network]
Bridge=brvlan3
```

```
==> 72-brvlan2.network <==
[Match]
Name=brvlan2

[Network]
DHCP=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
# Gateway=192.168.115.1
# NTP=
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
IgnoreCarrierLoss=yes

[Address]
Address=192.168.115.222/24
DuplicateAddressDetection=ipv4
Scope=global
```

```
==> 73-brvlan3.network <==
[Match]
Name=brvlan3

[Network]
DHCP=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
Gateway=192.168.116.1
# NTP=
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
IgnoreCarrierLoss=yes

[Address]
Address=192.168.116.222/24
DuplicateAddressDetection=ipv4
Scope=global
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this in the debug output:

```
onbunten.2: Failed to manage link by its new hardware address, ignoring: Die Datei existiert bereits
```

(*Die Datei existiert bereits* is German for *The file already exists*)

This led me to trying adding `MACAddress=` to the `[NetDev]` block of the `netdev` files for the VLAN interfaces (which I did not show above because I did not expect a problem there as the interfaces were created – but `DOWN`).

I assume that some change in Systemd or the kernel made this a requirement after it worked before without that entry, too. After all the documentation explicitly states that this does not have to be given...